# Why doe numpy.multiply give wrong result for large integers?

Tags: python, numpy, integer

Why does

```
np.multiply( np.array(100000) , np.array(100000) )
```

give 1410065408 which is incorrect but

`100000*100000` gives `10000000000` which is correct?

I know that using the non-integer 100000 works ok but why the wrong multiply result for integers?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It's not `np.multiply` but `np.array` that gives you the wrong result: You have 32bit integer system, and that is an overflow. Try:

```
 np.multiply( np.array(100000, dtype=np.int64) , np.array(100000, dtype=np.int64) )
```

Comment: Thanks. Perfect answer.  I suspected an overflow problem but did not know how to fix it.